# SQL Server - Need Join but where NOT Equal To

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I know how to do an inner join which gives one where there is a match.
I also need to get the records where there was not match.

What is the best approach. I guess I can do a left join and an inner join and then get the
ones that are left behind. Wondering what the best and cleanest approach would be.

As mentioned, I am already doing an inner join but also need to show records where there was no match.

Comment: Do you have any code that demonstrates what you have tried?

Comment: Do you want all the records including the matching and non matching records.  Or do you only want the non matching records?

Answer (score 91):

You probably are looking for an outer join or an outer excluding join.

OUTER JOIN

[image]

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
FULL OUTER JOIN tableB b
    ON a.column = b.column
```

OUTER EXCLUDING JOIN

[image]

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
FULL OUTER JOIN tableB b
    ON a.column = a.column
WHERE a.column IS NULL OR b.column IS NULL
```

[image: sql joins]

The graphs in this answer are taken from this very useful [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).

Comment: images are missing

Comment: I get "Unregocnized Keyword. (near "OUTER" at position 32)"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get values from both tables, you can use full outer join and take records which have one side as null:

```
select a.*, b.* from tableA a
full outer join tableB b on a.col = b.col
where a.col is null or b.col is null
```

Obviously this way all the values for either one table or the other will be null.