# JOIN and SELECT values not included in table2

Tags: sql

I appreciate this might be very simple for you guys but sometimes the logic behind JOIN can be difficult for beginners. I want to select "ID" from table1 but only those "ID"s which do NOT appear in table2."ID". I tested LEFT and RIGHT but cannot get it to work the way I need to. I am using dashDB.

Comment: Show us your left join attempt.

Comment: You should post your query as well ..

Comment: Hullo, I am not familiar with dashDB but please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602826/sql-server-need-join-but-where-not-equal-to

Comment: It will  much easier for all to  understand your question if you provide code you have tried , or a demo/details/output you wanted to get

Comment: `SELECT table1.ID FROM table1 left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id where table2.id is null` try using this query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NOT IN and subquery

```
Select * from table1 where id NOT IN (select id from table2);
```

Comment: are you kidding me? that simple? I feel like such a jackass. THANK YOU @Kugutsumen

Comment: Note that if table2 has a id which is NULL, no rows at all will be returned.

Comment: @jarlh thank you, that's a good point. luckily it's not possible in this particular case, but still thank you

Answer (score 3):

try this...

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
WHERE table2.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

I always prefer `NOT EXISTS` to do this

```
Select * from table1 a  
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from table2 b where a.id = b.id);
```

Here is a excellent article by *Aaron Bertrand* that compares the performance of all the methods

[***Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?***](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Comment: @MikePala - check the update it is a useful article. But it is specific to `SQL SERVER`

Answer (score 1):

Use the below script.

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```