# How to solve LEFT JOIN in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I made query like this:

```
select a.NIM
     , k.IPK
     , m.nama Mayor
  from kelanjutanstudi k
  left 
  join mahasiswamagister a
    on k.ID =a.MahasiswaID
  left 
  join mayor m
    on m.ID = a.MayorID
```

when I tried to run it, the result is not as I expected. Because the result is like this

[image]

Actually, NIM and Mayor have their own value, but when I run the query, NIM and Mayor had NULL value. Maybe, there are something wrong with my sql code. Here is my tables:

**mahasiswamagister table**

[image]

**kelanjutanstudi table**

[image]

**mayor table**
[image]

Please help me to solve that problem. Thankyou

Comment: One way is change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`. But IMO I think you should check the relationship between your tables again (join column).

Comment: could you please show me where is the error in my join column? Because I couldn't find it @PhamX.Bach

Comment: The query itself has no error, but as in `LEFT JOIN` when it has no rows matches then in result all columns not from main table will be NULL, so either you data is mismatch, or you join with wrong columns

Comment: Make sure that both your IDs are of the same type and collation (in case of strings). Usually these issues appear when your columns look identical yet are physically different.

Comment: Refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20602850/7012137)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

change `left join` to `Inner Join:`

```
select 
`mahasiswamagister`.`NIM` AS `NIM`,
`kelanjutanstudi`.`IPK` AS `IPK`,
`mayor`.`Nama` AS `Mayor`
from ((`kelanjutanstudi` 
inner join 
`mahasiswamagister`
 on((`kelanjutanstudi`.`ID` = `mahasiswamagister`.`MahasiswaID`)))
inner join
 `mayor` 
on((`mayor`.`ID` = `mahasiswamagister`.`MayorID`)))
```