# How do I know which lines are not in certain groups?

Tags: sql

I have two table `products` and `products_years`. The first table contains only the product id and name (but I just want the id). The second table contains the id and the start and end date of the period that it was marketed and the price of each product.

Table products is like this:

```
SELECT id from products
```

Results in the following output:

```
id 
1
2
3
4
5
```

And the query:

```
select Id, DateStart,DateFinish sum(price) as price from products_years
group by DateStart,DateFinish, Id
order by Id, DateStart
```

Results in :

```
Id DateStart DateFinish   price
1   2017        2019       100
2   2017        2019       200
3   2017        2019       40
2   2014        2016       30
4   2014        2016       140
```

I want to know which products stopped being sold in each period that they became available.

The output would be something like this:

```
id DateStart DateFinish
4   2017        2019
5   2017        2019 
1   2014        2016
3   2014        2016
5   2014        2016
```

Comment: why does your query not result in an error, telling about not using group by without using an aggregation function?

Comment: GROUP BY, but no aggregate functions involved - how come?

Comment: Show us some table1 and table2 data, and the matching expected result. Simplify if needed. [mcve]

Comment: This is only a example. It could have an aggregation function in the fourth column but it would not change anything. I have in table 1 only the id and in table 2 the id and dates. I have to check which id is not in each group in table 2. But I don't know which ids will appear in table 1. So I would have to join each group in table 2.

Comment: I contextualized the question to see if it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Compute all possible combinations of id and range and exclude those actually coming from table2.

```sql
with table1 (id) as (values
  (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
), table2 (id,datestart,datefinish) as (values
  (1,   2017,        2019),
  (2,   2017,        2019),
  (3,   2017,        2019),
  (2,   2014,        2016),
  (4,   2014,        2016)
)
select id, datestart, datefinish
from table1
cross join (select distinct datestart, datefinish from table2) dates
except
select * from table2
order by datestart desc, id
```

Note the example uses [PG12 syntax](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a66897da1264d3132f8005a07630c24c) though the query is universal.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're trying to find records in `table1` that are not in `table2`?

If so, you'll want to use [`JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). To do what you're looking for, you could use a `LEFT JOIN` and check for a null ID on the right (as in `RIGHT JOIN`, not as in "correct") table.

```sql
SELECT `Id`, `DateStart`, `DateFinish` FROM `table1`
    LEFT JOIN `table2`
        ON `table1`.`Id` = `table2`.`Id`
    WHERE `table2`.`Id` IS NULL
    GROUP BY `DateStart`, `DateFinish`, `Id`
ORDER BY `Id`, `DateStart`
```

That statement would return all records in `table1` that aren't found in `table2`.

Here's a great [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602826/sql-server-need-join-but-where-not-equal-to) that has some helpful visuals for using join statements.