# Left excluding join with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables (A and B) having identical structures. Table B is basically a subset of Table A. I want to retrieve all the records from Table A that are not present in Table B.

For this, I am considering Left Excluding Join ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602826/sql-server-need-join-but-where-not-equal-to/20602850)). Here is the query I am executing:

```sql
select a.id, a.category from a
    left join b
    on a.id = b.id
    where b.id is null;
```

As per BigQuery's estimate, the query will process 44.9 GiB. However, the query is taking unusually longer than expected to complete. Am I missing out on any important bit?

Comment: That is probably the most straightforward way of doing this.  You could also consider trying the `EXCEPT` set operator (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#except)

Comment: Query looks fine. Why do you say it is “taking unusually longer”? How long does it take and how long would you expect it to take?

Comment: @rtenha yes that is what I ended up doing. I used `except distinct`.